# Comparing POSIXct dates in R: best practice?

Tags: r, posixct

I am seeking some insight into the code behavior below. Make a new POSIXct variable by generating the format string from another variable with a specific time zone and using that time zone to create the new POSIXct.

```
eventTime1Converted <- as.POSIXct(format(eventTime1, tz = "GMT", usetz = TRUE), tz = "GMT")
```

Strangely, these two variables don't end up being equal:

```
> eventTime1Converted == eventTime1
[1] FALSE
```

In particular my 'GMT' timestamped variable seems to be 'less than' my 'EST' timestamped variable (the original variable). So it seems like when the numeric portion is equal, the timezones are then compared? If this is the case, what's the 'correct' way to check equality on two POSIXct variables? To compare their `as.numeric` values?

Comment: Please provide an example of `eventTime1`, i.e., `dput(head(eventTime1))`.

Comment: E.g., `format.POSIXct` by default discards fractional seconds, which could create this difference.